# GDI generic OpenGL driver - glBindTexture() - GL_INVALID_ENUM error

Tags: generics, opengl, textures, gdi

I have code fully working under graphics card OpenGL.

However when I switch to OpenGL emulation using GDI generic OpenGL driver I get very strange error:

GL ERROR - Function glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,1) generated error GL_INVALID_ENUM

The documentation of glBindTexture() says that GL_INVALID_ENUM can be returned only in case the target has wrong enum. GL_TEXTURE_2D is however correct enum - works on graphic card OpenGL driver.

I'm sure that:
1) The glBindTexture is generating that error - using GLIntercept tracker with error logging
2) Texture is allocated and has size of 512 x 4
3) Texture is assigned the data: glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, m_textureImage.width(), m_textureImage.height(), 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, m_textureImage.bits());
4) OpenGL context between assigning the texture the data and actually using the texture doesn't change - thou texture is unbound in-between

Is there some other undocumented reasons why it can return such error? Any ideas how to find the problem?

Comment: Are you sure that it's not glIntercept that's creating the error? I seriously doubt that the software generic driver is a common test case for glIntercept.

Comment: glintercept is not creating any errors of such kind, it's simply just checking for the errors after each call where possible.

Comment: glIntercept makes OpenGL calls behind your back. After all, if it didn't, it wouldn't be able to get errors. Therefore, it is entirely possible that it can generate errors from internal processes. Indeed, this was common before it's more recent release when running it on a core profile. Coupled with the fact that glIntercept was almost certainly *not* written to work with GL 1.1 only, and I'd say there's every chance that this error comes from glIntercept, not your code. And you can verify this easily by removing glIntercept and seeing if the error persists.

Comment: Hmm indeed you are right. Sorry then. It looks like the GlIntercept is generating that. Which is not nice since now I don't have a reliable way how to detect what is wrong with OpenGL. And the mesh is still not appearing on resulting image. :-(

Comment: OpenGL 1.1 is not generalled used for anything. So glIntercept isn't really designed to work with it. In short, you shouldn't be testing your code against the generic driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been identified as problem of GlIntercept image logger. The logger is using some OpenGL 1.2 enums which are not available in OpenGL 1.1.

The issue is being fixed for GLIntercept. Using GLIntercept without image logging should be safe for GDI generic OpenGL renderer.

Answer (score 2):

`glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1)` : it's unusual to assign a fixed texture ID: `(1)`, as opposed to a value returned from `glGenTextures`. That said, an invalid value shouldn't return `GL_INVALID_ENUM`.

Are you binding the texture 'name' (ID) as a `GL_TEXTURE_2D` before assigning the texture data via `glTexImage2D`? Does your GL driver support non-power-of-2 (**NPOT**) textures?

Finally, are you enabling texturing in the GL state: `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)`? Although I'm not convinced that would yield the error code you mention.

I don't really know. You might have done everything I've mentioned! I'm just trying to consider possible oversights.

Comment: *it's unusual to assign a fixed texture ID: (1), as opposed to a value returned from glGenTextures* - Technically this is legal as long as you're not using the Core Profile in version 3.2+. You used to be able to just assign any old integer as a texture and it would work fine. I believe in more current versions it's required to use glGenTextures, but it wasn't always that way.

Comment: I'm not binding texture ID 1 - this is from GlIntercept error message. Since the whole mesh didn't appear on the resulting picture which is rendered using OpenGL 1.1 array drawing support. I presume that it's because this glBindTexture is the problem.

Comment: My driver is supporting non-power-of-2 textures. GDI generic driver is not supporting that - but the texture is of size 512 x 4 which is power of 2 texture.

Comment: I'm enabling glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D) before binding the texture.

Comment: Would it be of any help if I post whole GLIntercept OpenGL call log? Thou wouldn't be any minimalistic - expect 200K+ size.